# stateProvider is not working on ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having side menu and main content section

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="side-menu-ctrl">
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">

        <!-- Left menu -->
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
            <h1 class="title">Menus</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                  <a href="{{task.url}}">{{task.title}}</a>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

        <!-- Center content -->
        <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
            <h1 class="title">Dashboard</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu-content>


    </ion-side-menus>
```

and my js is

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('/index',{
        url:'/index',
        templateUrl:'#/index.html'
    })
    .state('/about',{
        url:'/about',
        templateUrl:'#/pages/about.html'
    })
    .state('/faqs',{
        url:'/faqs',
        templateUrl:'#/pages/faqs.html'
    })
    .state('/contact',{
        url:'/contact',
        templateUrl:'#/pages/contact.html'
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})

.controller("side-menu-ctrl", function($scope,  $ionicSideMenuDelegate){
    $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
      };
    $scope.tasks = [
        { title: 'Home' , url:'/home'},
        { title: 'About Us' , url:'/about'},
        { title: 'FAQs' , url:'/faqs'},
        { title: 'Contact Us' , url:'/contact'}
      ];
})
```

based on controller i have creating list items in side menu. that is working.
When i clicking on side menu(time of changing stateprovider)
app gives `"ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"` error.

What is the mistake in this. Using of stateprovider and urlRouteProvider is right or wrong?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Check in answers of mine

Comment: Ok, so basically you have done what I told you to do, but you have created a new answer XD. It would be nice if you accept my response as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all these irrelevant hash character `#`

```
templateUrl:'#/index.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

The hash (**#**) is something that AngularJS includes by default in your routes (not in your file paths), so Pete is right, you must remove **#** from your templateUrls, **but you should also add** the **#** **into the href** urls.

So your code should look like:

```js
//...some stuff...

$stateProvider
.state('/index',{
  url:'/index',
  templateUrl:'index.html'
})

//...some stuff...
$scope.tasks = [
  { title: 'Home' , url:'#/home'},
  { title: 'About Us' , url:'#/about'},
  { title: 'FAQs' , url:'#/faqs'},
  { title: 'Contact Us' , url:'#/contact'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed href to use ui-sref from the ui.router package so you can change url by simply calling the state name :)

```
    <!-- Left menu -->
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
        <h1 class="title">Menus</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasks">
              <a ui-sref="{{task.url}}">{{task.title}}</a>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>

    <!-- Center content -->
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
        <h1 class="title">Dashboard</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu-content>


</ion-side-menus>
```

The templateUrl should point to your template location also i don't the state name should contain any slashes

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('index',{
        url:'/index',
        templateUrl:'/index.html'
    })
    .state('about',{
        url:'/about',
        templateUrl:'/pages/about.html'
    })
    .state('faqs',{
        url:'/faqs',
        templateUrl:'/pages/faqs.html'
    })
    .state('contact',{
        url:'/contact',
        templateUrl:'/pages/contact.html'
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
})

.controller("side-menu-ctrl", function($scope,  $ionicSideMenuDelegate){
    $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
      };
    $scope.tasks = [
        { title: 'Home' , url:'index'},
        { title: 'About Us' , url:'about'},
        { title: 'FAQs' , url:'faqs'},
        { title: 'Contact Us' , url:'contact'}
      ];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added # in url

```
.controller("side-menu-ctrl", function($scope,  $ionicSideMenuDelegate){
    $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
      };
    $scope.tasks = [
        { title: 'Dashboard' , url:'#/dashboard'},
        { title: 'About Us' , url:'#/about'},
        { title: 'FAQs' , url:'#/faqs'},
        { title: 'Contact Us' , url:'#/contact'}
      ];
})
```

Removed the # from templateUrl

```
.state('dashboard',{
        url:'/dashboard',
        views:{
            'menuContent':{
                templateUrl:'pages/dashboard.html'
            }
        }

    })
    .state('about',{
        url:'/about',
        views:{
            'menuContent':{
                templateUrl:'pages/about.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

It is working..